# echo <form> tag doesn't work in view script zend framework

Tags: forms, zend-framework, view

If I echo a `<form>text</form>` tag from my view script (with or without PHP), the `form` HTML tags isn't displayed in Firebug, only the text. Why are them removed by Zend?

In my view script:

```
<?php
echo "<form>ds</form>";
?>
```

Firebug displays only:

```
ds
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem solved :) My mistake was: I didn't add ending tag to the view helper's form

Answer (score 1):

It's *probably* not being removed by Zend, it's *probably* being removed by Firefox/Firebug when inspecting the DOM.  For starters, that's not a valid use of the `form` element.  It's missing [required attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.3).  Also, without any sort of actual *form* being used, the HTML rendering engine may be smart enough to just discard it entirely.

In Firebug, check the actual response from the server on the Net tab to see if the tag is present there.  If it is, then it's being removed client-side and not server-side.

Comment: <?php
echo "<form method=\"POST\" action=\"something.php\">ds</form>";
?>

Comment: even if I add name, id, enctype

Comment: @user1560141: Is the code included in the response from the server or not?  Is it being removed client-side or server-side?  Without any actual elements which make it a usable form, I'm still under the impression that the browser is discarding the `form` element.  It's probably the browser's subtle way of telling you that you don't actually need to include this `form` element since you're not using it anywhere.

Comment: How can i check, if it was removed client or server side?
I tried it in another module, and there works fine...

Comment: @user1560141: As stated in my answer: "In Firebug, check the actual response from the server on the Net tab to see if the tag is present there. If it is, then it's being removed client-side and not server-side."

Comment: Is it possible, if there is a form in a plugin, wich contains an another form will block all form declaration I mentioned above?

Because I removed a plugin's form section and the form appeared...

Comment: @user1560141: Yes, it's certainly possible that other code you haven't mentioned could be affecting the DOM.  If you're talking about JavaScript plugins which specifically target and modify `form` elements then that's pretty likely.

Comment: It is only a zend plugin extending Zend_View_Helper_Abstract , but it doesn't have any js manipulation. Do I should see in firebug->net->html the form? Because there is no form(but there is in firebug-if I don't display the plugins form)

Comment: sorry, not a plugin, just a view helper

Comment: the problem solved :) My mistake was: I didn't add ending tag to the view helper's form